# Div hover only working at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div a link, which on hover should zoom in and show another overlay div. This is what I have. It works, but not all the parts of the div work with the hover. It only works at the bottom of the div but not anywhere else.

Please what am I doing wrong?

I have put my code below. Funny how it works for background-home-row-2 and doesn't work well for `.background-home-row-1`. What am I omitting?

```js
$("a.image").hover(function() {
  $(".background-home-row-1 .visible-on-hover").css("display", "block");
}, function() {
  var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px)");
  if (!mq.matches) {
    $(".background-home-row-1 .visible-on-hover").css("display", "none");
  }
});


$(".background-home-row-2").hover(function() {
  $(".background-home-row-2 .visible-on-hover").css("display", "block");
}, function() {
  var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px)");
  if (!mq.matches) {
    $(".background-home-row-2 .visible-on-hover").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```css
.image-box {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}
.background-home-row-1 .visible-on-hover,
.background-home-row-2 .visible-on-hover {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 100px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
  background: red;
  font-family: geomanist-medium;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
div.background-home-row-1 {
  background: url("../assets/images/home_image1.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
div.image-box:hover div.background-home-row-1,
div.image-box:focus div.background-home-row-1,
div.background-home-row-1:hover,
div.background-home-row-1:focus {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
div.background-home-row-2 {
  background: url("../assets/images/home_image2.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
div.image-box:hover div.background-home-row-2,
div.image-box:focus div.background-home-row-2,
div.background-home-row-2:hover,
div.background-home-row-2:focus {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 image-box">
  <a href="#" class="white-text image">
    <div class="background-home-row-1" style="border: none;">
      <div class="visible-on-hover" style="border: none;">Click here to view</div>
    </div>
    <script>
    </script>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 image-box">
  <a href="#" class="white-text">
    <div class="background-home-row-2" style="border: none;">
      <div class="visible-on-hover" style="border: none;">Click here to view</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: If row-2 works, why not use the same selector for your .hover() on row-1?   In the first one you select a.image and for the second you grab .background-home-row-2. You should also look at breaking out the js from the html more and refactoring duplicate code when you can.

Comment: If only parts of an element react to the mouse cursor, then most often it is due to other elements laying on top of it. Go use your browser’s dev tools to investigate that.